# php gd library second imagejpeg doesn't work

Tags: php, gd

For some reason, only the first imagejpeg is working. help?

**FULL CODE**

```
<?php

imagecopymerge($image, $watermark, $dest_x, $dest_y, 0, 0, $watermark_width, $watermark_height, $opacity);
imagejpeg($image, "modified-images/".$codigo2."_modified_picture_status_".$status.".jpg");
$image2 = "modified-images/".$codigo2."_modified_picture_status_".$status.".jpg";
imagestring($image2, $font_number, $x_position, $y_position, $text, $drawing_color);
imagejpeg($image2, "modified-images/".$codigo2."_modified_withtext_picture_status_".$status.".jpg");

?>
```

Comment: Any errors?Care to share a little more code. Where does $image2 come from?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

[`imagestring`](http://www.php.net/imagestring) expects an image resource, not a string with a pathname. You probably want to use one of the createimagefrom* functions, or continue working with your existing `$image` resource (after all, you already saved the intermediate image how you liked it, why not after that add text to the same image, and save precious cpu cycles).